Azure DevOps Server 2022 on-prem Collection database size is not decreasing after deleting projects
I am trying to migrate from on-prem Azure DevOps Server 2022 to Azure DevOps Service. My collection database size is 104 GB. I have deleted all projects except two but still database size is 104GB. How do I reduce it?
I have deleted from the Admin Console so its deleted permanently no soft delete but db size is still same.

When you delete the resources in Azure DevOps Server Admin Console, it will not immediately prune data from the database.
It will marks stuff as deleted for later processing.
To force the cleanup to happen immediately, you can run the following command on your Project Collection database.
EXEC prc_CleanupDeletedFileContent 1

EXEC prc_DeleteUnusedFiles 1, 0, 100000

Note: Before you running the sql command to delete the data in database,  you had better to backup the DBs first.
For more detailed info, you can refer to this blog: Clean up your Team Project Collection prior to migrating to VSTS
Update:
For Azure DevOps Server 2022, there was a change on the Stored Proc. This will clean up more metadata, before actually removing the BloB. you have to run it twice.
EXEC prc_CleanupDeletedFileContentSegmentedBatchSelect 1,0,0,1,0

EXEC prc_CleanupDeletedFileContentSegmentedBatchSelect 1,0,0,1,0

Then we can remove the actual blob from the database(specifically tbl_content). Below are two options you can take which shows the different parameters you can use:
Option1:
exec prc_DeleteUnusedFiles @partitionId=1, @retentionPeriodInDays=-1
--go

Option2:
EXEC prc_DeleteUnusedFiles @partitionId = 1, @retentionPeriodInDays = -1, @chunkSize = 1000
--go


prc_CleanupDeletedFileContent and prc_DeleteUnusedFiles work in older versions but it's not available in ADO Server 2022.

@user25077041 When you run the command above, what issue have you encountered?

Could not find stored procedure

@user25077041 Refer to the update in the answer, I have shared the latest sql commands to delete the data in sql. These commands can be used in Azure DevOps Server 2022. You can try it.

The first command show ContainerItemsDeleted, FileReferencesDeleted, BlobReferencesDeleted all 0 . 2nd command also run successfully but database size didn't decrease

After running the command, can you try to restart the Azure DevOps Server and check the database size?

Ran the commands then rebooted the server database size is same

Can you check what is in the sql database that is large in size?

We only have two databases The Configuration database and collection database. The collection database is very large

Can you check which tables in the database have large size?

tbl_content 101 GB

Can you refer to the sql query in this link: https://jessehouwing.net/tfs-clean-up-your-project-collection/ to check the detailed large part?

VersionControl : 100493.6846 MB CodeSense : 239.1197538 MB, FileContainer : 0.052174567 MB

From the result, the version Control is the git OR tfvc related source.   What kind of version control are you using in Azure DevOps Server?

We use tfvc no git repo

Since you are using tfvc repo, can you run the tf vc command in the link https://jessehouwing.net/tfs-clean-up-your-project-collection/  to clean the old workspace data?

@KevinLu-MSFT We recently updated to DevOps 2022.2 and want to clean up before migrating to the cloud. But our DB does not have the procedures "prc_CleanupDeletedFileContent" or "prc_CleanupDeletedFileContentSegmentedBatchSelect". How can we do the cleanup with the latest update?
